# Python - Imprimir un cuadrado de * sin ningún tipo de ciclo

Tags: python

Este es un ejercicio que saqué de Pywombat. La consigna era realizar un cuadrado a través de una función sin ningún tipo de ciclo. El código que sigue es la solución. Entiendo que la variable `limit` multiplica el string por el parámetro que se le asigne, pero no entiendo qué hace `body`. ¿Para qué multiplica `cantidad -2`?
También veo que final hace algo similar, multiplica el `body` y a `cantidad` le resta `2`.

No sé si es correcto pedir ayuda para poder entender este código. Intenté buscar los ejercicios con las explicaciones, pero en gitHub no salen los mismos. Alguien podría ayudarme a comprender? Gracias.

```py
def cuadrado(cantidad):
    limit = "*" * cantidad

    body = '*' + ' ' * (cantidad - 2)  + '*' + '\n'
    print(body)
    final = limit + '\n' + body * (cantidad - 2) +  limit
    print(final)

cuadrado(8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te explico en comentarios tomando como ejemplo `cuadrado(8)`:

```
def cuadrado(cantidad):
    limit = "*" * cantidad
    # limit = "********" 
    # limit tiene `cantidad` asteriscos porque se usa para marcar
    # el lado superior e inferior del cuadro
    
    body = '*' + ' ' * (cantidad - 2)  + '*' + '\n'
    # body = *      *
    # para el body se coloca un asterisco al inicio luego se rellena con espacios
    # que son 6 o sea (cantidad -2), son 6 espacios porque hay dos asteriscos, uno al 
    # inicio y otro al final. Eso suma los 8 caracteres.
    
    
    final = limit + '\n' + body * (cantidad - 2) +  limit
    
    # el final se compone de limit (********)
    # luego se multiplica el body (*      *) por 6 (cantidad -2) porque
    # limit se imprime al inicio y al final y esos son los dos caracteres que se restan
    print(final)

cuadrado(8)
```

Comment: Gracias Lobos por tomarte un tiempo y explicarme!

Answer (score 3):

En Python puedes multiplicar cadenas por enteros. El resultado de esto es otra cadena con el contenido de la original repetido.

Por ejemplo `'a' * 5` produce la cadena `'aaaaa'`.

Ahora, recordemos que el objetivo es producir un cuadrado como este:

> * * * * * 
> *         * 
> *         * 
> *         * 
>  * * * * *

En la función, al multiplicar un asterisco por el tamaño del lado del cuadrado, produce una línea horizontal de asteriscos:

> * * * * *

Esta la utiliza como el lado superior e inferior del cuadrado.

> * * * * * <---
>
> . . .
>
> * * * * * <---

---

Las líneas del medio son todas iguales. La manera en que las genera es similar. Cómo a los extremos va un asterisco, los puedes identificar en la línea:

```
body = '*' + ... + '*' + '\n'
```

Lo que convenientemente reemplacé por una elipsis es la separación entre los extremos del cuadrado. Son 2 extremos así que la separación es de 2 caracteres menos que el tamaño del lado del cuadrado.

La expresión `' ' * (cantidad - 2)` es la encargada de generar esta separación.

Ahora, con los `+` concatenas las cadenas obteniendo algo así:

> *         *

Por cierto, `\n` representa un salto de línea.

Hasta ahora solo tienes una línea de las que van entre los extremos. La cantidad es el tamaño del lado del cuadrado menos 2 nuevamente. Entonces al multiplicar la línea por ese valor obtienes todas:

> *         * 
> *         * 
> *         *

---

Finalmente concatena todo, obteniendo el cuadrado:

```
final = limit + '\n' + body * (cantidad - 2) +  limit
```

`limit` son las líneas horizontales y `body * (cantidad - 2)` crea la parte que acabo de mencionar del cuadrado.

---

Nota: añadí espacios entre los asteriscos solo para que se vea mejor en la respuesta. El resultado puede variar según la fuente de la consola.

Comment: Mateo, te agradezco mucho la explicación!

Answer (score 2):

Haciendo uso de formato de cadenas queda (quizás) un poco más legible y ordenado:

```
def cuadrado(cantidad):
    hueco = cantidad-2
    top = "*{}*\n".format("*" * hueco)
    mid = "*{}*\n".format(" " * hueco)
    bot = "*{}*\n".format("*" * hueco)
    cuadrado = top + mid * hueco + bot
    print(cuadrado)
```

He definido las variables `top`, `mid` y  `bot` para que contengan el lado de arriba de la caja, una línea de la zona central, y el lado de abajo de la caja (este último es igual al de arriba, pero por simetría me pareció más bonito declararlo también como variable).

Cada uno de esos se construye con una cadena de formato `"*{}*"`, es decir, empieza y termina con un asterisco y lo que varía es la zona central, representada ahí por `{}`. Esa zona central se reemplaza por una serie de asteriscos o por una serie de espacios, según estemos en la parte top/bot o en la parte mid. Para crear la serie de asteriscos o espacios uso la multiplicación de cadenas que ya te han explicado en otras respuestas.

Una vez tengo esos tres elementos, el cuadrado se crea concatenándolos, según la fórmula: `top + mid*hueco + bot`. Como ves, se vuelve a aplicar la multiplicación de cadenas para repetir la fila central el número de veces necesario.

**Postdata**. Siempre me ha parecido muy elegante el hecho de que Python admita la sintaxis `cadena * numero` para repetir y concatenar una `cadena` un `numero` dado de veces, pues es perfectamente consistente con el resto del lenguaje. Ya que la multiplicación por `n` equivale a sumar `n` veces, y la suma de cadenas es la concatenación, tiene sentido que `cadena + cadena + cadena` sea lo mismo que `cadena*3`.

Comment: Gracias, por explicarme!